# Homomorphisms of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

This is a  problem which I am trying to solve. Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of order $6$. If $f:G\to G_1$ ba an epimorphism of groups such that $H\subseteq\ker f$.Then show that $G_1$ is also a  homomorphic image of $G/H$.

My try: By using 1st Isomorphism Theorem $G/\ker f$ is Isomorphic to $G_1$.
Now I define a mapping $g:G/H\to G_1$ by $g(aH)=f(a)$ for all $a\in G$.
Clearly it's easy to verify that $g$  is well defined and homomorphism. Now we take any $x\in G_1$, since $f$ is an epimorphism we must have $b\in G$ such that $f(b)=x$. Hence from the construction of $g$ we get $bH\in G/H$.So  $g$ is on to.So my problem is solved.But i think somehow I have done something wrong as I didn't use the order of $H$ and the fact $H\subseteq\ker f$, so my question is where did I wrong in my try, I will be happy if someone give me another approch to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did use $H \subset \text{ker}(f)$, you used it in the step where you proved that $g$ is well-defined.

And no, you did not use that $H$ has order $6$. So ask yourself, does your proof remain valid when $H$ has order $42$? Or does it remain the proof valid without any assumptions at all on the order of $H$? If so, then you are free to keep that hypothesis or drop it, the theorem will still be true. And every theorem gets better if you can remove unnecessary hypotheses.

Comment: mosher I have realized that I used that to show $g$ is well defined.If I  take the epimorphism $f:Z_84->Z_21$,we get $kerf$ is the set {$[0],[21],[42],[63].I choose $H$  is $ {[0],[7].[14],[21],[28],[35],[42],[49],[56],[63],[70],[77]}$, ie.$kerf$$\subseteq$$H$.$H$ is a subgroup of  commutative group $Z_84$,The $g$ as i defined above satisfy the desired result,So I think order of $H$ is unnecessary and I'm going to drop it to find the result.

Comment: I apologise for wrong use of latex,I need to learn it properly, those are z_84 and Z_21,I did try to  correct it but the maximum time to edit comment 5 min expired.